# Rails search table clickable link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, hyperlink

I have a keyword search page for which the results are presented in a table. One of the fields in this table is a url which I want to display as a clickable link when the field has one in it but I can't get this working, when the link is clicked it instead queries the search again. I think the problem is due to the def within the searches controller dealing with the keywordsearch view. Can anybody help?

Below is the keywordsearch view which contains the results table:

```
<!-- Index of all Courses -->
<% provide(:title, "Courses Page") %>


<!--Breadcrumbs -->
<br>
<%= link_to "Back", :back %><br><br>

<!--Page Contents --> 


  <div class ="row">
    <h1>Degrees Offered</h1>
    <%= image_tag "line.png" , :alt => "line break"%>    
  </div>

  <div class ="row">

      <!-- Form for Keyword Search, to query database for University courses. It is hidden so as to not appear as a search on the page -->
      <div class = "hidden">         
      <%= form_tag(keywordsearch_path, :method => "get", id: "search-data") do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search course" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
      <% end %>
      </div>     
      <% if @search_degree != nil %>
      <% end %>

      <% if @search_degree != nil %>
        <table border="1" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>University Name</th>
              <th>Course Name</th>
              <th>Duration</th>
              <th>Qualification</th>
              <th>Entry Requirements</th>
              <th>Course Page</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% @search_degree.each do |degree| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= degree.uname %></td>
              <td><%= degree.cname %></td>
              <td><%= degree.duration %></td>
              <td><%= degree.qualification %></td>
              <td><%= degree.entry %></td>
              <td> <a href=<% degree.url %>>View course page on University Website</a></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Below is portion of the search controller in which keyword search is defined:

```
  def keywordsearch
    @search = Degree.all.select(:uname, :cname, :ucas, :duration, :qualification, :entry).distinct.order(id: :ASC)
    if params[:search]
      @search_degree = Degree.search(params[:search]).order('uname ASC')
    end
  end
```

The link from all of this is clickable but rather than taking me to the correct url it redoes the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead of hardcoding the `<a> tag`:

```
<%= link_to 'View course page on University Website', degree.url %>
```

Can you also post a sample of url? Be sure to include the protocol (e.g, http://...)

Comment: That fixes the old problem but brings a new one. The url is now included at the end of the webpage now, but not as a separate link. An example link would be http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/L600/ - with http://www. at the start too. But instead of going there it just adds /%22http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/L600/%22 to the end of the link. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems the problem is the missing protocol (http://) in the URL. You have two options: 1) edit all urls in your DB to include http:// or 2) do something like `link_to 'link text', "http://#{degree.url}"`

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to get the protocol to show up on the comment. The protocol is present in the database.

Comment: the http // www is present within the database and is called accurately through the code. Just it adds the url to the end of the websites homepage as opposed to opening the link separate of everything. If you get me. Sorry for not being as clear as I could be.

Comment: alright, let's try this `link_to 'link text', url_for(degree.url), target: "_blank"` ..this must work!

Comment: For some reason it still appends the correct html link, including protocols, to the homepages url and provides the following error: No route matches [GET] "/%22http:/www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/L600/%22"

Comment: I think the error is somehow related to the double quotes " that I see before and after the url, so that rails does not see the correct full link and interprets it as a relative path, but I really do not understand why they are there :(

Comment: Thanks for your help, if they are the problem I can try removing the quotes before they are stored in the database, which will hopefully solve that problem if it is the case.

Comment: ah! so in your DB you have links between double quotes.. that must be the problem. Let me know if it works, I'm pretty curious now!

Comment: Will update you once the scrape is finished and database repopulated.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, the double quotes in the database. With those removed your last suggestion works dandy, and I'm guessing your first one probably will too. Thanks for the help.